# Windows 8 App with Azure WCF Service

Tags: xaml, azure, windows-8

I have a Windows 8 app that I want to connect to a WCF Service hosted on Windows Azure - easy.

The tricky part is that I want to allow only Authenticated users (via their windows live account) to access my service, including being able to pass a unique identifier to the service to identify the user on the Azure hosted app.

All of this plumbing is available when you use Azure Mobile Services, but surely there must be a solution for a regular WCF app within azure.

Azure Mobile Services has a `MobileServiceClient` type that has all of the required functionality, but I need a regular Azure-hosted WCF equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You can try pulling some of the content from the now deprecated [Windows Azure Toolkit for Windows 8](http://watwindows8.codeplex.com/).  For the moment the [Release Preview version](http://watwindows8.codeplex.com/releases/view/84166) is available; it won't work as is since it's pre-RTM, but it should help jumpstart your effort.

I'll re-emphasize though that it's not supported and Windows Azure Mobile Services is the plan of record.